# Retrieve the name of a document which saved in a SharePoint library using Client Object Model

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

```
        foreach (SPListItem item in listitems)

        {
            AttachmentControlTemplate atch_templt = new AttachmentControlTemplate(countr);
            atch_templt.lnk_btn.Text = item.File.Name;
            atch_templt.lnk_btn.OnClientClick = "window.open('" + site_url + "/" + item.File.Url + "')";

        }
```

Above sever side code shows the way of retrieving the name of a document which saved in a SharePoint document library by using "item.File.Name",i have done this completely, but how do i do same thing by using Client Object Model. What should i use instead of "item.File.Name".

Would anyone help me to sort this out ??

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just now i found that i can retrieve the particular file name by using            " currentmodule.get_item("LinkFilename")", but how can i retrieve the url of that particular file ?

Comment: finally i have found the way to get the Url of a saved document. i am sharing it with others. i have  retrieved the file name and concatenated with the Url of the document library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i have found the way to get the Url of a saved document. i am sharing it with others. i have  retrieved the file name and concatenated with the Url of the document library.

var fileUrl = "Document library Url" + "File Name";

By using above fileUrl,  the document can be opened.